# nicEditor link problems in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, hyperlink, nicedit

I'm using [nicEdit](http://nicedit.com/) with the "link" button. And I have different problems with Chrome and Firefox when: I **don't select any text** and introduce a link and a title,  then click *Submit Query*.

In Chrome, a link with the correct URL appears but with the content "javascript:nicTemp();" (ie, that's the html between the  tags).

In Firefox the results is different: nothing happens.

**Does anyone have a clue of how to fix/change this behavior?**

If you download the nicEdit source you'll be able to see the executed code in *src/nicLink/nicLink.js*

Answer (score 4):

There are forks on GitHub that have this fixed, e.g.: https://github.com/danishkhan/NicEdit

Answer (score 0):

I experimented the same problem with nicedit (Version 0.9 r23 released January 4th, 2009. )
when using FF6.0
Finally, when pressing link button with a selected text AND do'nt filing the link text, it works.